# internally store a double variable on click of a button

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to figure out how I can store a double variable type internally, on the click of a button so that when the app is completely exited it will remember that from the last time the save button was pressed upon launching again.

I have been trying to get it to work for the past 2 hours and cant get it.

[image]

If this doesn't make sense to people please let me know and Ican try and explain it better.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers
Evan

Comment: You probably want to write to file. This is how things usually is done no matter OS and HW. That is, if you want to terminate the program completely. For android it is also possible to minimize, programs put them in sleep mode, etc. I am not entirely sure which state you want the app to be in. Apart from this, write code, do not post code as an image.

Comment: You are not storing nothing on "your_prefs". Only reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the double to its 'raw long bits' equivalent and store that long. When you're reading the value, convert back to double.

Because the two data types have the same size you don't lose precision and you won't cause an {over,under}flow.

```
Editor putDouble(final Editor edit, final String key, final double value) {
  return edit.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
}

double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
 return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key,   Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe float is enough and you can use `SharedPreferences.Editor#putFloat` method to store it?